Cant get my node express project to work on the computer
my screen broke on my first laptop so i got a new one, i unzipped my file and into VS but im getting this error when i just try and run my code
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Anita\Downloads\Coursework Prac\app.js' at Module._   resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15) at Module._   load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at
node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []``
}
Please someone help me!!!!
I tried changing the pages to html rather than ejs and that worked but i need it to be ejs


Modul app.js tidak ada di direktori C:\Users\Anita\Downloads\Coursework Prac.
Nama modul app.js salah atau tidak sesuai dengan nama file yang sebenarnya.
3.Direktori C:\Users\Anita\Downloads\Coursework Prac tidak ada atau tidak dapat diakses.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Are you certan that you haven't missed node_modules dir?
Try to install packages again by running npm install
